# Can the ROS visp_tracker be used in hybrid mode

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The current visp_tracker seems to only use edges. Can it be switched to use both edges and key-points?

It seems the underlying tracker is geared for mbt+klt, but I don't know how to change it from just mbt to hybrid (mbt+klt) tracking type.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233120/can-the-ros-visp_tracker-be-used-in-hybrid-mode/) by [BernhardHengst](https://answers.ros.org/users/26724/bernhardhengst/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-04-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `tracker_type` param could be set to:

- `mbt`: meaning tracking with edges only
- `klt`: tracking with keypoints only
- `mbt+klt`: hybrid tracking using edges + keypoints

`

```
<node pkg="visp_tracker" type="tracker" name="tracker_mbt">
    <param name="camera_prefix" value="/wide_left/camera" />
    <param name="tracker_type" value="mbt+klt" />
</node>
```

---

Originally posted by [Fabien Spindler](https://answers.ros.org/users/3990/fabien-spindler/) with karma: 126 on 2016-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BernhardHengst](https://answers.ros.org/users/26724/bernhardhengst/) on 2016-05-21**:
Thanks Fabien. I managed to get this to work shortly after I posted the question, but neglected to comment. I found that tracking with both edges and key points, the tracker seemed to get lost more easily in a cluttered environment.